# Using AesManaged for CTR encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I'm trying to use this code https://gist.github.com/hanswolff/8809275 to make a CTR encryption/decryption. But when I encrypt and then decrypt i do not get my plain text back. I found several references to this code, and from the comments it seems to be a good implementation. So what am I doing wrong?

```
byte[] initialCounter = new byte[] { 0xF0, 0xF1, 0xF2, 0xF3, 0xF4, 0xF5, 0xF6, 0xF7, 0xF8, 0xF9, 0xFA, 0xFB, 0xFC, 0xFD, 0xFE, 0xFF };
    byte[] Key = new byte[] { 0x2B, 0x7E, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xAE, 0xD2, 0xA6, 0xAB, 0xF7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xCF, 0x4F, 0x3C };
    byte[] data = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF };

    aes128CounterMode = new Aes128CounterMode(initialCounter);
    encryptor = aes128CounterMode.CreateEncryptor(Key, null);
    decryptor = aes128CounterMode.CreateDecryptor(Key, null);

    encryptor.TransformBlock(data, 0, 16, endata, 0);     
    decryptor.TransformBlock(endata, 0, 16, roundTrip, 0);
```

Comment: You need to create a new Aes128CounterMode object for the decryptor. You might also need to make a copy of the `initialCounter` array.

Comment: That did the trick, Thanks!